# AngularJS Unknown provider with simple module dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 modules: core, util and test.

- util has no dependencies, has one provider
- test depends on util and core and has one controller
- core depends on util, has one provider which uses provider from util

With dependencies set up like this I get error on initializing core module, because it can't find provider from util. If I remove this provider injection, everything works fine.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
var util = angular.module('util', []);
var core = angular.module('core', ['util']);
var test = angular.module('test', ['core', 'util']);


core.provider('core.OC', ['util.Path', function(Path){
  this.$get = function(){
    return {
      get: function() { return 'OC!';}
    }
  };
}]);

util.provider('util.Path', function(){
  this.$get = function(){
    return {
      get: function() { return 'Path!';}
    }
  };
});

test.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','util.Path', function($scope, Path) {
  $scope.name = Path.get();
}]);
```

Here's plnkr of this setup:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7VhdrdleNXHqqucSUcv9

Comment: I don't believe you can namespace the name of a provider, have you tried `util.provider('Path', ...)`?

Comment: Yes, tried that.Controller in test works, even if the name is 'util.Path', but when I add 'util.Path' to core.provider, everything stops working.

Comment: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: util.Path`. Thats weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try injecting util.Path into your factory function instead.  The provider call for core.OC is run to early to inject util.Path.  You have to inject it later, when the factory function is run.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7vBszzVlo14q0pljOarv?p=preview

```
core.provider('core.OC', function(){
  this.$get = ['util.Path', function(Path){
    return {
      get: function() { return 'OC!';}
    }
  }];
});
```